# How to redirect requested uri that don't exists to 404 page with Apache?

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I've now used rewrite to achieve part of my goal:

```
rewriteengine on
rewritebase /
rewriterule ^([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)$ resume.php?user=$1
```

How to add the 404 part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use [ErrorDocument](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#errordocument) rather than mod_rewrite:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /yourUrl.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Apache ErrorDocument directive to direct 404s to a particular URI.

For example:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /resume.php
```